# Insert an integer after some integer in binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I want to write an **integer** to **binary** file which inside it there are a lot of **integers**.
I want to know how to **insert** an integer **between** file without changing the value of integers **before** and **after** it.
The problem with below code is that it changes the value of the integer after file pointer.

```
int a=5;
fwrite(&a,sizeof(int),1,fp);//fp is a FILE *
```

Comment: **what** is the **speciality** of the **bold** use?

Comment: also, any specific reason you din't use `fprintf()`?

Comment: because it's a binary file and it's recommended to use fwrite.I don't think it will make any diffrence using fprintf().

Comment: @SouravGhosh: obviously **that** is because the **OP** believes **we** might miss **the** most important words. Alas: SO does **not** support `<blink>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple you can do is read the file into memory then write the first half back to the file then insert your integer and then continue writing the rest of the file. Or you can use fputs or fprintf to append to the end of the file your integer.